# How can I set alignment to named style in openpyxl?

Tags: openpyxl

I'm trying code below, but alignment is not set to named style in xlsx.

Is any wrong?

env: Python3.5.1, openpyxl 2.4.7

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, styles

st = styles.NamedStyle('SAMPLE')
st.alignment = styles.Alignment(horizontal='center')
bk = Workbook()
bk.add_named_style(st)
bk.save('output.xlsx')
```

*Additional:*

If below, alignment has been set to cell correctly.
But, it has not been set to named style of the workbook.

```
bk.add_named_style(st)
cl = bk.get_active_sheet.cell('B1')
cl.style = 'SAMPLE'
cl.value = 'sample'
bk.save('output.xlsx')
```

[named style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiOQQ.png)

Comment: Can I make a suggestion, Stick with common variable names: instead of `bk` use `wb` and instead of `st` something more descriptive like `centredstyle`

Comment: Try adding the `value` first before adding the `style` ? @Charlie-Clark

Comment: Additional code is only description to my question.
And exchanging the order of 'cl.style=' and 'cl.value=' wasn't effective.